# ionic - get error ':processDebugGoogleServices' when phonegap-plugin-push installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When phonegap-plugin-push installed in my project, I try to run my app on the device and getting an error:

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':processDebugGoogleServices'.  Please fix the version conflict either
>   by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information
>   about the latest version is available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.2.0.

How can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Will post something if I find a fix.  Did you find any answers?

Comment: No.... @Richard

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled the fcm plugin and just use the `phonegap-plugin-push` plugin, and now it works for me.